# asp.net mvc 5 template for collection of properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, templates, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I want to group up some controls of a model with a template (preferable not hardcoded in C#). In case something changes on the layout I can just edit the html of the template instead of changing it in every view.

This is what I've got so far:
**Views\EditorTemplates\InputBlock.cshtml**

```
<section class="pure-g">
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in ViewData)
    {
        if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Any(x => x.PropertyName == item.Key))
        {
            <div class="pure-u-1-2">
                @Html.Label(item.Key)
                @Html.Editor(item.Key)
                @Html.ValidationMessage(item.Key)
            </div>
        }
    }
</section>
```

And I'm using that template like this:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model, "InputBlock", new { Model.FirstName, Model.LastName, Model.LastLogin, Model.Id })
```

This works, it renders all Controls as they should be with the correct type.

The problem is it ignores any attributes added to the model like *[Required]* or *[DisplayName]*, so the label shows the property name instead of the value set as DisplayName, even though the properties in ModelMetadata have the correct DisplayName set.

The Server-Side validation does work aswell. No unobtrusive validation attributes are added when *[Required]* or *[StringLength]* is defined, only the default ones for the specific data type ones are set (like datetime or int)

How can I easily group up multiple controls in a template with Attributes still working, preferable changeable without recompiling the project?

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)` or `@Html.EditorForModel()`